# Bind Value in a Label

Tags: java, javafx, bind

is it possible to bind a Double-Value from a JavaFX Slider to a Label?
I would like to get something like this:

```
m_maxSlider = new Label("Right Slider Val: " + m_slider.getValue1());
m_maxSlider.textProperty().bind(Double.toString(m_slider.getValue1()));
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are `getValue1()` and `getValue2()`? Are there property accessor methods associated with them?

Comment: No the Property Accessor Methods are called value1Property()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a property accessor method `value1Property()` returning a `DoubleProperty`, you can do

```
m_maxSlider.textProperty().bind(m_slider.value1Property().asString());
```

If you want to format the string using a [Formatting String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), do something like

```
m_maxSlider.textProperty().bind(m_slider.value1Property().asString("Value: %.2f"));
```

Comment: Sounds nice and works. Is there a possibility to cast the double to a int value?

Comment: If you just want to display the int value, just use "%.0f" as the format.